# Count numbers in text field

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that contains cells similar to this:

```
AAA Up 3
AAA Down 2
BBB Up 1
BBB Down 3
CCC Up 5
CCC Down 2
```

So it's always some sort of text, followed by `Up` or `Down`, and then how often it went up or down. I'd like to count how many times went up or down. In this example the total of Up would be 9, and Down 7. How do I do that in Excel/Google Sheets? I couldn't find a combination of functions that would help me get this problem solved.

I forgot to mention that each row here is one cell. Or in other words, all of the text above is one column only.

Thank you.

Comment: Use sumif or sumproduct

Comment: Numbers can be of 1 digit or n number of digits?

Comment: n number of digits, but always at the end.

Comment: See the answer proposed, in that case, it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume only 1 or 2 digits in the number field then for *Up* use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(A1:A6,2))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Up ",A1:A6)))
```

and for *Down* use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(A1:A6,2))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Down ",A1:A6)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward in Google Sheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(split(A:A," "),"select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col2"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion.

A **single** formula, **shorter** than [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762321/1527780) by Erik and **more robust** [than the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760137/1527780) by Tom.

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\w+ \d+$")," ")), 
         "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 1):

There are many replies here. I'll suggest another and then tell you why it may be different:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")," ([UpDown]+ \d+)$")," ",0),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 Label SUM(Col2) ''"))`

It's not clear from your post whether "AAA," "BBB," etc. will be solid blocks of alpha-numeric information in your real application. I can imagine that the opening text might actually be strings with spaces (e.g., "Joe Schmoe from Idaho UP 3"). If so, some of the other formulas I see here will fail; but this formula will account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit crude, but it'll work.  Let us assume your data is in A2:A7 like this

```
AAAAAA Up 300
AAA Down 2
BBB Up 10
BBB Down 3
CCC Up 5
CCC Down 2
```

Enter this array formula in cell B2 (and copy downwards) [don't forget to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789"))+1))
```

Enter `Up` in `C1` , `Down` in `D1` and then enter this formula in C2 (and copy downwards and then rightwards so that cells C2:D7 are filled with this formula)

```
=--NOT(ISERROR(FIND(C$1,$A2)))
```

Now to sum `Up` values - use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C7,B2:B7)
```

and for `Down` use this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D2:D7,B2:B7)
```

You'll get desired sums

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but I think one row in the sample is one cell in `Excel` (the numbers are not aligned and *Count numbers in text field*). Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, @VBasic2008, I just saw that I made the mistake here of not mentioning that the text is all in one cell. I'm going to edit the question. Thank you Anil for the effort.

Comment: I have revised it.  Please see.  It'll work for any number of digits

Answer (score 0):

I see that a game of "whose is shorter" has begun. First (for those who don't know), a shorter formula doesn't necessary hold any advantages over a longer one as far as processing ability or speed. In fact, a formula that is a bit longer may hold benefits in terms of ease of understanding, getting rid of superfluous elements, etc.

That said, it seems to be, as I say, a sort of game for people who write formulas often to cut characters. So with only fun in mind, I toss this into the hat as well:

`={"Up",SUM(FILTER(SPLIT(A2:A," "),FIND(" Up",A2:A)));"Down",SUM(FILTER(SPLIT(A2:A," "),FIND(" Down",A2:A)))}`

It's shorter than [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759720/count-numbers-in-text-field/65763001#65763001) by **marikamitsos** and gets rid of the "sum" header, which may or may not be wanted. It also allows for "Up" to be at the top without extra code (or by switching the clauses around, it gains no length and allows for "Down" to be at the top if desired).